# Javascript nested loop - Ajax/Json

Tags: javascript, json, loops, for-loop

I have a problem in my javascript loop see code below.

I am trying to get child-a-a-a working in this loop see JSON below, in console it's showing the content but when I use a nested loop it's giving an error
(Cannot read property 'length' of undefined).

please let me know if you need more details or if its not clear

```
var obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
obj.onload = function () {
    var data = JSON.parse(obj.responseText);
    var menuItems = '';
        menuItems += '<ul id="nav">';
    for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
        menuItems += '<li id="nav-1">';
        menuItems += '<h2>' + data[a].label + '</h2>';
        menuItems += '<ul id="nav-2">';
        for (var b = 0; b < data[a].child.length; b++) {
            menuItems += '<li>';
            menuItems += data[a].child[b].label;
            menuItems += '</li>';
            for (var y=0; y < data[a].child[b].child.length; y++) {
                menuItems += data[a].child[b].child.key;
            }
        }
        menuItems += '</ul>';
        menuItems += '</li>';
    }


    menuItems += '</ul>';
    document.getElementById('nav').innerHTML = menuItems;
}
obj.open('GET', 'test.json', true);
obj.send();
```

//json

```
   [
{
    "key":"parent-a", 
    "label":"Parent-A", 
    "child":[
        {
            "key":"child-a-a", 
            "label":"Child a a", 
            "content":"this is the parent A content hallo world",
            "child":[
                {
                    "key":"child-a-a-a", 
                    "label":"Child a a a", 
                    "content":"this is the parent A AA content hallo world"
                },
                {
                    "key":"child-a-a-b", 
                    "label":"Child a a b", 
                    "content":"hallo world this is child A A B"
                },
                {
                    "key":"child-a-a-c", 
                    "label":"Child a a c", 
                    "content":"this webpage is awesome"
                }
            ]            
        },
        {
            "key":"child-a-b", 
            "label":"Child a b", 
            "content":"hallo world this is child b"
        },
        {
            "key":"child-a-c", 
            "label":"Child a c", 
            "content":"this webpage is awesome"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "key":"parent-b", 
    "label":"Parent-B", 
    "child":[
        {
            "key":"child-b-a", 
            "label":"Child b a", 
            "content":"this is the parent B Code is working fine"
        },
        {
            "key":"child-b-b", 
            "label":"Child b b", 
            "content":"your job is done now!"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from this specific section of your code:

```
for (var y=0; y < data[a].child[b].child.length; y++) {
  menuItems += data[a].child[b].child.key;
}
```

If you try to access `data[1].child[0]` or `data[1].child[1]`, you will get `undefined`. Thus the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. What you can do is check if a property is an array before using the for loop.

```
//var childB = data[a].child[b].child; => edit
var childB = data[a].child[b];
if(childB.child && Array.isArray(childB.child)) {
  for (var y=0; y < childB.child.length; y++) {
    menuItems += childB.child.key;
  }
}
```

Since you have a repeating nested property called 'child', what you can probably do is create a function to check if the property has a property called child AND the property called child is an array.

Comment: Hi Brian 

i followed the logic and worked, in your if statement you left the ".child" 

                var childB = data[a].child[b].child;
                if(childB && Array.isArray(childB)) {
                  for (var y = 0; y < childB.length; y++) {
                    console.log(childB[y].key)
                    menuItems += childB[y].key;
                  }

Comment: Woops, my bad. Btw, you have to do the same for all the 'child' properties, otherwise you might run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a semicolon to end of your onload function, that's what causing the problem.

```
  menuItems += '</ul>';
  document.getElementById('nav').innerHTML = menuItems;
};   //  <----
obj.open('GET', 'test.json', true);
obj.send();
```

---

PS: use double quotes not single quotes.